# How to execute .exe file in a remote windows machine using python

Tags: python, windows, remote-access

I have a Executable file in remote windows machines.How can I execute .exe file remotely using python? or How can I get access to remote windows command line?.Please help.

I have credentials of remote windows machines?

PS: All remote windows machines are in a same network

Answer (score 0):

use command line program psexec.

if you need to control remote computer through python I recommend you install on the remote computer rpyc. on the website of rpyc there is documentation on how to use it.

Comment: I cant install rpyc in all remote mahines.I am doing an automation tool.
Can u provide link to psexec documentation.

Comment: psexec is part of microsft sysinternals downloadable from the microsoft website.

I use it to install python and rpyc on remote machines and the control the machine with pure python.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `wmi` package after I have tried 'pywinauto', 'paramiko', 'winrm' and 'pypsexec'.

For 'paramiko', I set ssh service on both server side and client side well and can get ip information from my python script, but can't execute .exe with RunTimeError showing in my IDE console.

For 'winrm', I also set some config well by inputting something like `winrm s winrm/config/client @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}` and can get ip information from my script but still can't get exe executed, either.

For 'pywinauto', it just shows `Not a GUI element`. For 'pypsexec', the package is blocked by my company's security due to regarding as spyware.

From my experience, I just use `wmi` to achieve my goal successfully. Here is some code snippet for executing an exe file.

```py
import wmi
from socket import*
SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

connection = wmi.WMI(computer = 'YourRemoteIP', user = 'DomainUserName', password = 'pwd')

process_startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL
process_id, result = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="cmd.exe /c C:\\Users\\DomainUserName\\Desktop\\testbat.bat",ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
if result == 0:
  print("Process started successfully: %d" % process_id)
else:
  raise RuntimeError
```

There are some steps you should do first:

1. Start the wmi service on both server and client side: Run `cmd` as administrator and input `net start winmgmt`.
2. Write a `batch` file as execution target: For instance, if you just want to run an exe file, you just need to write `start cmd /c "cd /d YourPath&&EXE.exe"` in a text editor and save as a .bat file.
3. Run the script and you will get the job done.

Finally maybe you need to know what wmi is, you can refer [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/wmisdk/starting-and-stopping-the-wmi-service).
I hope this can help you.